# Controlling jQuery-ui Autocomplete's dynamic positioning

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

So I'm trying to understand why jQuery-ui's autocomplete, with appendTo used to attach the results dropdown to a div, still dynamically positions the results with absolute positioning. Like this:

```
top: 38px;
left: 8.5px;
width: 251px;
```

Creating issues like:

[image]

Can I turn off this dynamic positioning? I would like full control over the UI for fluid responsivity and custom styling. I cannot find an answer online.

**UPDATE:**
So it seems that each widget has different rules, is this correct? I figured out responsive width for jQuery-ui Dialog popup by

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ width: auto });
```

& in my stylesheet, applying a max-width to the wrapping dialog class.

```
.ui-dialog{
  max-width: 720px;
}
```

However top and left are still a mystery as of yet.

Comment: What's going wrong? In the image you posted, it looks like the dropdown results window is positioned correctly.

Comment: I would like control over its width. And to remove its dynamic positioning, left and top. It is within the same div as the field yet is much wider because of these styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS used by either editing the jQuery UI CSS file, or else just overriding it in your own CSS, such as:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete { width: 250px !important; max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'm trying not to have to override. I was just hoping I can turn off dynamic styles for all jQuery-UI. So I can style anything anytime, anyway.